# How to enable DAG Processor status in Airflow

Tags: airflow, status, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, health-monitoring

I have an Airflow cluster running with Docker. Everything seems to work fine except DAG Processor is not properly bound.

When checking the cluster status it is set to Unknown:

[image]

Thus I am investigating how to make the DAG Processor able to get its status right.

I have confirmed components are running fine and do have healthy status:

```
docker ps | grep airflow
b3945b8cd533   apache/airflow:2.7.1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   3 days ago   Up 3 days (healthy)   8080/tcp        airflow_airflow-webserver_1
c19eb3571734   apache/airflow:2.7.1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   3 days ago   Up 3 days (healthy)   8080/tcp        airflow_airflow-worker_1
07403ea2cdd0   apache/airflow:2.7.1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   3 days ago   Up 3 days (healthy)   8080/tcp        airflow_airflow-scheduler_1
6b53355eae24   apache/airflow:2.7.1   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   3 days ago   Up 3 days (healthy)   8080/tcp        airflow_airflow-triggerer_1
1f8dfbc2766b   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago   Up 4 days (healthy)   6379/tcp        airflow_airflow-cache_1
53c2926b6eea   postgres:16            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago   Up 4 days (healthy)   5432/tcp        airflow_airflow-database_1
```

Checking the [configuration](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-processor-manager-log-location), logs are properly defined:

```
dag_processor_manager_log_location = /opt/airflow/logs/dag_processor_manager/dag_processor_manager.log
```

And the file does exist at the required location:

```
docker exec -it airflow_airflow-worker_1 bash
ls -l /opt/airflow/logs/dag_processor_manager
total 18444
-rw-rw-r-- 1 default root 18880639 Oct 10 06:15 dag_processor_manager.log
```

Here is my questions: Why my DAG Processor status is Unknown? And, how should I configure the cluster to get this status properly bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are running a standalone DagProcessorManager component in your environment. [As of Airflow 2.3.0, the DagProcessorManager can be run as a separate process](https://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-2.3.0/#dagprocessormanager-as-standalone-process-aip-43) to take decouple some responsibility away from the Scheduler.

This configuration is disabled by default, but you can enable it via the [`standalone-dag-processor` config](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#standalone-dag-processor). Once enabled, the DAG Processor health should display as you'd like [from the `/health` endpoint](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/check-health.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there any advantage to enable this option?

Comment: A few: a standalone DAG Processor will parse DAG instead of the Scheduler (i.e. the DAG Processor runs as it's own process rather than as a subprocess of the Scheduler); you can spin up multiple DAG Processors for different DAG directories (if you want separation between teams in large org for example); decouple the Scheduler from running user code (i.e. DAG code).

Comment: More details here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dagfile-processing.html

Comment: @jlandercy In Airflow 2.7.2 (being voted on now), the DAG Processor health status will be hidden if you are not running it as a standalone process: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/33611